# Vue3 - компиляция, не разделять файлы

Tags: vue3

Vue3 в стандартной сборке через `vue create appname` при сборке `npm run build` делит файлы `css` и `js` в папки `dist/js` и `dist/css`. У меня своеобразный хост, не позволяет создавать подпапки на сервере. Скажите пожалуйста можно перенастроить так что бы он складывал всё в одну папку просто `dist/` без всяких подпапок?

Comment: Лучше откажитесь от «своеобразного» хоста

Comment: Мой хост - `res://exename.exe/RC_DATA/INDEX.HTML`

Не получиться от него отказаться :D :D :D